# Can the second and third operand of a ?: expression be statements?

Tags: javascript

I get a syntax error with

```
false ? {var x = 1;} : {var x = 2;}
```

But when just use expressions for the last two operands, I don't run into any problems.

Do I have to resort to conditionals?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to assign? Objects? Values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explicitly answer the question, no, the 2nd and 3rd operands *must* be expressions, and cannot be statements.  Here's the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/Conditional_Operator

Note the syntax: *condition ? expr1 : expr2*

---

Edit: just an interesting side-note is that since function calls are expressions and you can pass contexts around, you can kind of accomplish what you were trying to do.  It's horrible. Don't do it. But you can...

```
console.log(typeof x); // undefined
false ? (function() { this.x = 1; }).call(this) : (function() { this.x = 2; }).call(this);
console.log(typeof x); // number
```

Comment: Thanks for the accept! Also, I just added a code snippet to demonstrate some behavior similar to what you were trying to do in your code example.  It's hideous and only of academic value really, so... take it or leave it (but you should probably leave it)... :)

Comment: Disregarding readability, I think it is a very creative workaround :) Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

That type of thing is done with an IF statement.

```
if (false) { x = 1; }
else { x = 2; }
```

To do so with your syntax:

```
var x = false ? 1 : 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Note: this is chock full of my personal bias]

Just stop using the ternary operator, it is terrible and ridiculous.  It **never** makes the code easier to read.  Just use an if statement.  If your target audience is a maintenance programmer, clarity is generally a desirable trait of code.

```
var x;
if (false)
{
  x = 1;
}
else
{
  x = 2;
}
```

[Bias to 11!]
If you think the target audience of code is either a compiler or a browser, they you need to get your head in the game and stop programming like a goof-rocket.  Humans maintain code not compilers and browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It's always valuable to know what's considered best practice.

Comment: I will not claim that my technique is a "best practice", but I will claim that my technique makes it easier for (me at least) to maintain code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work because `var x` is always going to be out of scope after this happens. You're not doing anything with it after you declare it, so any reference to it will break.

You need to declare `var x` outside of this first:

```
var x;
false ? {x = 1;} : {x = 2;}
```

Think of this in terms of writing out the `if`'s (which is the same thing by the way)

```
if (false)
{
    var x = 1;
}
else
{
    var x = 2;
}
// can't do anything with x here, because it doesn't exist
```

Comment: That's not the problem here. It's just not valid syntax for a ternary operator.

Comment: Yeah good call. But also he has to know this code won't work right. Unless he never wants to use what he's assigning.

Comment: Of course. But the first block of code in your answer still isn't valid and causes a syntax error.

Comment: As Xeon06 said, it's invalid syntax.  If it was valid syntax, `x` actually *would* be in scope, because variables are function-scoped, not block-scoped.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid syntax. Here's how you would do it:

```
var x = false ? 1 : 2;
```

And, you should not define the same variable in two places, which is bad practice. You may want to read up on [variable hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting).

Answer (score 0):

That's not how object notation works. Your syntax error is not the ternary operator, but your object notation.

```
false ? {x: 1} : {x: 2}
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

The second and third parameters need to be wrapped in parenthesis, not curly braces to execute code within a conditional.

```
Math.random() > .5 ? (console.log('1')) : (console.log('2'));
```